# wpf listview binding to multiple sources

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

```
 <ListView x:Name="lvPayload" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Payload}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=0x{0:x2}, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource hexConverter}}" FontSize="15" Margin="2,1,2,1" MinWidth="25" MinHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center"></WrapPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            </ListView>
```

I have that OneWay binding mode set on the TextBox.Text property. It's clear that the collection behind will not be updated. But anyway i didn't set this as a TextBox with no reason. I still want to make some changes and i don't want them to be reflected in the original collection but elsewhere. I don't know if i can accomplish that, can someone give me a hint for this ? And after the eventual modifications, if i iterate through the Items of the list, i will get back the values from the original collection, the ones not modified and i just need the new values.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to create your own custom binding for this (your own class inheriting from Binding class and overriding the set operation)

It's quite a large topic onto itself, and your implementation will vary according to the requirements you have for the set target, but that's the place to start.